# Why is read (r) denied to a 777 file?

Tags: server, permissions, samba, dns

I'm following the instructions at [the Samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/BIND9_DLZ_DNS_Back_End) to set up BIND9 DLZ as the DNS backend for my Active Directory Domain Controller. However, I can't even get `named` to start. It wants write access to a file, but can't get it...

```
named[886]: /etc/bind/named.conf:9: open: /var/lib/samba/private/named.conf: permission denied
named[886]: loading configuration: permission denied
named[886]: exiting (due to fatal error)
systemd[1]: bind9.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
kernel: [    5.004922] audit: type=1400 audit(1502211678.138:9): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf" pid=906 comm="named" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=114 ouid=0
systemd[1]: bind9.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
systemd[1]: bind9.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: bind9.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I thought I must have messed up the permissions somehow, but running `ls -l /var/lib/samba/private/named.conf` gives me:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 678 Aug  8 17:56 /var/lib/samba/private/named.conf
```

Since the permissions were 664, any user should have been able to access the file. Even doing `chown bind:bind` (definitely the correct user, see kernel log), or **setting permissions to 777 doesn't fix the problem**.

The puzzling part is `apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf" pid=906 comm="named" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=114 ouid=0`.

What am I missing/don't understand?

Comment: From that message, apparmor is denying read permission. Edit your apparmor profile and give write permission.

Comment: `chmod 777` is never the correct answer.  Never.

Comment: @Rinzwind I wasn't trying to imply it was, I was using 777 to confirm that permissions were not the issue.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Thanks, I'm editing my config now. EDIT: Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppArmor was blocking the read. I went to /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named and added the line:

```
/var/lib/samba/private/named.conf r,
```

which allowed named to read the file.